# In Grunt, what's the difference between **.js vs **/*.js?

Tags: gruntjs

I've seen both `**.js` and `**/*.js` in some open source projects. As I understand it, `**/*.js` targets all .js files in all folders recursively.

Then, what does `**.js` mean? Does it mean the same thing as `**/*.js` or `*.js` or something else?

Comment: You might have to test it to see how it behaves. The little bit of documentation of `**` in [Configuring tasks](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks) makes me suspect that `**.js` is going to be equivalent to `*.js`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `**` is the so-called globstar and it works the same as in bash: It matches directories recursively. The documentation of the [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) library (which Grunt uses internally) states:

> This is supported in the manner of bsdglob and bash 4.1, where ** only has special significance if it is the only thing in a path part. That is, a/**/b will match a/x/y/b, but a/**b will not.

In other words, `**.js` means the same as `*.js`.